# nginx is not passing fastcgi query string

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

With some (or very much) trial and error i was able to modify my copy and pasted nginx fastcgi php configuration from somewhere years ago to be able to run my php application in a subfolder.

But the last final step i am not able to solve is how to get nginx to pass the query string to php to be able to access the GET parameters. This is my configuration mostly perfect with only the configuration parameters missing:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name project.dev;

    location /app/ {
        alias /path/to/my/application/;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        }
    }

    location / {
        # configuration for static website
    }
}
```

I read that there are different options you have to pass to `try_files` to get request parameters:

- `try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.php$is_args$query_string;`
- `try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.php$is_args$args;`
- `try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.php?$query_string;`

Unfortunately changing it to any of these results in my php script no longer being found because nginx resets the request to it's document root:

```
2016/11/25 11:54:48 [error] 45809#0: *1169 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx-full/1.10.2/htmlindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: project.dev, request: "GET /app/myurl?test=works HTTP/2.0", host: "project.dev", referrer: "http://project.dev/app/myurl?test=works"
```

Providing an absolute path for `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` does not work too producting the same error. Even setting a `root` configuration on the `server` level does not work correctly, because the separating slash for the path and the `index.php` is omitted everytime. But (if possible) i would prefer without setting a root directory at the server level because this project is consisting of many different folders and applications on the filesystem sharing no common directory.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What files do you have under `/path/to/my/application/`?

Comment: my complete application is saved under `/path/to/my/application/` with all its assets and it's php. Loading of the assets and running the php works exactly as expected, but for some reason i can't pass the $_GET parameters to the fastcgi

Comment: The problem is `alias` and `try_files`. You want to run your application under the URI `/app`, things would be **very** simple if `/path/to/my/application/` ended with `/app` (the same subdirectory name as the URI).

Comment: Thats sadly not possible because the location `/` is another website with it's own filesystem and structure i am not allowed to mess with. But `try_files` with `alias` **is** working perfectly: PHP gets called, assets are sent - only the request parameters are not sent to PHP. It only goes downhill as soon as i add these suffixes to get the query string.

Comment: Is there just the single `PHP` file under `/path/to/my/application/`? BTW all you need to do is make a directory called `app` where your files are and move them into it - I'm not asking you to change anything in `/`.

Comment: Yes there is a single php file. Creating a directory called `app` is not possible to, because this is a bought solution and the vendor will reject any bug reports if we make a single change - even only changing the directory of the assets. "Enterprise Applications" ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129057/discussion-between-richard-smith-and-tobias-p).

Answer (score 3):

You have an application installed under `/path/to/my/app2/public` and would like to access it using the URI `/app`.

Assuming that we can use `/app2/` as an internal URI (which does not collide with any other public URIs served by this server - but importantly will not be seen by your customers).

You have one PHP file.

```
location ^~ /app {
    rewrite ^/app(.*)$ /app2/public$1 last;
}        

location ^~ /app2/ {
    internal;

    root /path/to/my;
    index index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /app2/public/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/my/app2/public/index.php;
    }
}
```

The first location block simply alters the internal URI to match the document root (so we can use root instead of alias). The second location block serves the static content. The third location block invokes `index.php`.

How `index.php` gets the query string is program dependent. It will use one of the parameters defined in `fastcgi_params`. Usually either REQUEST_URI or QUERY_STRING. Either way, both variables should be preserved with the above configuration.

The `^~` modifier ensures that these location blocks take precedence over other regular expression location blocks (should any exist). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.